# How to reduce echo/noise in PJSIP iOS application when turn on speaker

Tags: objective-c, asterisk, pjsip

I have a PJSIP library used in my iPhone based ​Siphon Project by Samuel Vinson application. Everything is working fine except one issue. When i turn on speaker or conferencing there are lots of echo/noise in the call and it impossible to have conversation. What could be an issue and how to deals with this?

Comment: Turn or stun server can be a problem. what codec are you using? do you lissen the noise during the call? without speaker?

Comment: stun server is blank, means not using any stun server. Yes listening the noise without speaker on as well , when turn on the speaker, situation get worse and impossible to talk. I am using codec - ulaw, alaw, ilbc, g722 order.

Comment: try speex... you try with other devices?

Comment: I can give change to test with speex as well. What do you mean by other devices!!

Comment: I'm not testing in IOS I never developed for it... but as the stack is the same in android I should get the same error...

Comment: maybe the problem can be from device

Comment: what version of pjsip are you using?

Comment: using latest version.

Comment: 2.5.0? I only use 2.4.5. sorry I can't help this way I never tested